# Allow app access for only specific FB users

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Ultimately, I want a white list of User IDs that have access to management portions of my application.  I was hoping to use Facebook Authentication and associated user profile IDs to handle this.

Currently, I have:

```
if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
   if (user != null) {
       // Set the id for the ProfilePictureView
       // view that in turn displays the profile picture
       profilePictureView. setProfileId(user.getId());

       // Set the Textview's text to the user's name
       userNameView.setText(user.getName());

       // Set the Textview's text from user's id
       userId.setText(user.getId());

       String approved = "553660552";

       if(user.getId() != approved){
          //553660552
          userId.setText(user.getId());
        } else {
          userId.setText("Goodie");
        }

   }   
}
```

Where `user.getId()` returns 553660552, yet the comparison fails. (It also fails when approved is a different value).

To summarize, `user.getId()` returns 553660552 (in this case). I need to be able to make a matching comparison for white listing. Yes, any `String` set equal to "553660552" does not match

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .equals() method of your string to make the comparison ie,

```
if (approved.equals(user.getId()))
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a few searches looking for this answer, but it very obviously appears to be a basic Java question, and has nothing to do with Android or the Facebook SDK.